# how to combine two tables in django

Tags: sql, sql-server, django, django-models

There are two tables

Hookahs and tobacco for example

and for the basket model, you need to combine these two models, help

For example:

```
class Hookah(model.Model):
    name = models.Charfield()
    description = .....
    price = .......

class Tabacco(model.Model):
    name = models.Charfield()
    description = .....
    price = .......
```

and OrderItem model:

```
class OrderItem(model.Model):
```

and here I need to pass the top two models, as a product, how to do it?
i.e. combine Hookah and Tabacoo into one

please help me

Comment: combine them how?  Maybe explain what you're trying to do, what you tried, and how the results with what you tried differ from what you're expecting?

Comment: I want to create a basket class if there was one class like hookah
then class OrderItem:

 product = models.Fk (Hookah)

and I need to combine Hookah and Tabacco and pass them to OrderItem ()
example

OrderItem:
 product = models.Fk (Hookah, Tobacco)
somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a `Basket` model that stores a link to other types?  You can do that by creating a parent model that each shopping item inherits from, or you can do it by using a `GenericForeignKey` which allows pointing to any model object.  The shared parent model is probably better as you don't have to duplicate code for shopping items such as `name`, `price`, etc.

```py
class ShoppingItem(model.Model)
    name = models.Charfield()
    description = .....
    price = .......

class Hookah(ShoppingItem):
    height = ....

class Tabacco(ShoppingItem):
    flavour = ....
```

Then you can do something like one of the following:

```py
class OrderItem(model.Model):  # info on a single ordered item
    item = models.ForeignKey(ShoppingItem, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

class Basket(model.Model):  # basket of many `ShoppingItem`
    items = models.ManyToManyField(ShoppingItem)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case, you should probably look at building a single product model and have a type attribute separate the product types. That way you can FK to a single product model with your order item model.

Something like this:

models.py

```
class Type(models.Model):
    ...
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ...


class Product(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.TextField()
    type = models.ForeignKey(Type, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

class Order(models.Model):
    ...
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    ....
```

Comment: This code is for the same fields in the product

But I have different fields in Hokaah and Tabacoo

Comment: Yes that was purposeful. From an attribution/data model perspective, what is the difference between the hookah and the tobacco? In my opinion they are both products you intend to sell so there’s no sense in placing them in separate models.

Comment: they have different fields

Comment: Usually, this is handled through the use of a main product table/model with a separate attribute table/model as the attributes of the product can vary but the core data required for the product to be considered a product don't. This way you can use a single FK in your Order model/table without having to add complexity. Another thought would be to avoid the FK relationship altogether and just insert an ID as needed along with a type attribute in the Order table.